# How to disable CompositeDiscoveryClient and SimpleDiscoveryClient in service discovery library

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, service-discovery

We've written an in-house service discovery (SD) client based on the [spring-cloud-commons SPI](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-commons), meaning it provides implementations for interfaces `ServiceRegistry` and `DiscoveryClient` and some other Spring-provided abstractions.

Apps that use our library merely add it to their pom file, and it autowires the `DiscoveryClient` with its own implementation, `InHouseDiscoveryClient`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>blah.blah<groupId>
   <artifactId>inhouse-service-discovery-client<artifactId>
<dependency>
```

However, rather than referring to `InHouseDiscoveryClient` in code, it's best practices to use the interface `DiscoveryClient` as shown below

```
# Good 
@Autowired
DiscoveryClient client;

# Bad (binds app to a particular SD implementation)
@Autowired
InHouseDiscoveryClient client;
```

As such, we are required to add `spring-cloud-commons` to the project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

*This is where the issue starts*.  The commons library actually autowires two additional implementations of `DiscoveryClient` - the `SimpleDiscoveryClient` and the `CompositeDiscoveryClient`.

This makes for an odd user experience for our clients.  Instead of simply having `InHouseDiscoveryClient`, users find themselves with these additional beans.

Is it possible to prevent `spring-cloud-commons`'s `DiscoveryClient` implementations from autowiring?  And if so, can this be done in our library rather than in the end-user's applications?

Comment: Why are the other beans a problem?

Comment: Well - it's more of a source of confusion than anything.  For example - say we implemented the `description()` method of `InHouseDiscoveryClient` to return something informative like the email address for our support team.  Users call this method and get "Composite Discovery Client" and I anticipate they would be confused by this and possibly think something is wrong w/ their config.  So we'll either need to clearly describe this behavior in our documentation (ie. that 3 beans are autowiring and not 1).  What is the use-case for having multiple clients, maybe I don't understand?

Comment: I'm trying to determine if there is a technical problem or not. Users wanted to be able to sidestep a discovery system and put entries in configuration for various reasons. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/140 it's going on a few years old.

Comment: To turn them off you need to exclude https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/composite/CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.java and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.java via properties `spring.autoconfigure.exclude`

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb - I had actually done this using ExclusionFilter - have updated answer.  I don't think there's a technical problem per-se, but the linked issue seems like a specialized usecase which perhaps should be opt-in?  I'd be happy to discuss my use case at more length if that would help, but to be honest we just wanted to use the commons interfaces/abstractions and found some of the default implementations to be in the way.  Perhaps it would be possible to split the commons abstractions into a standalone submodule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extended `AutoConfigurationImportFilter` in my library to remove the autowired beans from cloud-commons.  I also removed it's health indicator, but we had a very particular reason to do so - most probably would rather keep it.

```
my.package

public class StratusDiscoveryExclusionFilter implements AutoConfigurationImportFilter {

private static final Set<String> SHOULD_SKIP = new HashSet<>(
        Arrays.asList(
                // DiscoveryClient Beans
                "org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.composite.CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration",
                "org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration",
                // Health indicators
                "org.springframework.cloud.client.CommonsClientAutoConfiguration")
);

/**
 * For each class name, provide an assocated boolean array indicated whether or not to include
 */
@Override
public boolean[] match(String[] classNames, AutoConfigurationMetadata metadata) {
    boolean[] matches = new boolean[classNames.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
        matches[i] = !SHOULD_SKIP.contains(classNames[i]);
    }
    return matches;
 }
}
```

I think add a reference to this in my library's `spring.factories` file

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter=my.package.MyExclusionFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two `AutoConfiguration` classes that need to be excluded.

You can do that through the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class, SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Or through the properties file as `@spencergibb` suggested:

```
# yml version
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.composite.CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration
```

```
# classic version
spring.autoconfigure.exclude= \
  org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.composite.CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration, \
  org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration
```